# regex Y-M-D extraction from web scraping

Tags: python, regex, screen-scraping

I wouldl like to extract the Y-M-D information from the following html.

```
Created at</th><td><span><time datetime="2001-06-01"
```

```
date= [re.search("Created at</th><td><span><time datetime=([0-9A-Za-z\&;]*)", address).group(1)]
date
```

I have tried this code but it does not work.Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The first argument in `re.search` should be the pattern and the second the string you want to extract from.

You can start trying something like:

`re.search("\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}", 'Created at</th><td><span><time datetime="2001-06-01"')`

And then use groups

Answer (score 0):

Try using a capturing group to isolate the date portion of the regex pattern.

```
date = re.search(r'time datetime="(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})"', address)
print(date.groups())
```

output:

```
('2001-06-01')
```